# My App Screen appears wrong way round on the physical device

Tags: android

When i am installing my app on my device, it appears wrong way round.
The application title appears on the top right side on the screen and the menu appears on the top left side of the screen. On the emulator everything is look OK.

is anyone have an idea why it happened?
is it related to the fact that my default phone language is "Hebrew" which is going from right to left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with the fact that the phone is "rtl" (right to left).
I'm facing these issues from time to time as well (fellow Israeli here). Android has a concept of "start" and "end", which replace the normal "left" and "right".

For example an English phone will have it "start" value as left, while on a "rtl" phone, like hebrew or arabic, the "start" is the right.

If you want to disable this feature - add `android:supportsRtl="false`" to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks ! change the SupportRtl to false solved the problem.

Comment: @ZionCohen Great, glad I could help you.
 An upvote/correct answer would help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

> is it related to the fact that my default phone language is "Hebrew"
>   which is going from right to left?

Yes it is. 
Check also your app's manifest for this line:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

change this attribute to `false`.